connection error with SQLAlchemy and flask in docker container
I've a simple flask application and it's using Mysql database and the each of these services run in different docker container. The problem is when I start the docker container and the pages that doesn't need database works well, but when I try to access a team page which needs database it gives me error connection: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"). and after like 2 seconds when I refresh it works fine and I didn't get that error again. Note that this error only occurs when I access the web page immediately after starting the container.
app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URI")
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    CGPA = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/team")
def team():
    return render_template("team.html", team=Team.query.all())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")


init.sql:

use cloudy_members

CREATE TABLE team
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR
(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL,
    CGPA FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CGPA_range 
    CHECK
(CGPA >= 0 AND CGPA <= 4.0)
);

INSERT INTO team
VALUES
    (22010200, 'example', 19, 2.4),
    (22010201, 'example', 19, 3.2),
    (22010202, 'example', 19, 3.1),
    (22010203, 'example', 19, 3.2);

Dockerfile:
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=mysql+pymysql://root:2004@mysql:3306/cloudy_members
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=2004
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cloudy_members
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db_data:

requirement.txt:
Flask
PyMySQL
Flask-SQLAlchemy
cryptography

I tried to delay the team page alittle bit and it works fine. but it's delay every time I access it
